# How can I calculate the sum of child values on a hierarchical table?

Tags: sql-server

My Table

```
create table tbl_trial_balance
(
    ID int primary key,
    Name char(20) not null,
    Parent_code int references tbl_trial_balance(ID), -- Self Join
    Debit float,
    Credit float
)
go

INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(1,'Assets',null,null,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(2,'Current Assets',1,null,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(3,'Bank Account',2,null,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(4,'DBBL A/C',3,5000,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(5,'DBBL A/C',3,4000,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(6,'DBBL A/C',3,3000,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(7,'DBBL A/C',3,null,7000);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(8,'IFIC A/C',3,3000,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(9,'IFIC A/C',3,5000,null);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(10,'IFIC A/C',3,null,6000);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(11,'IFIC A/C',3,null,9000);
INSERT INTO tbl_trial_balance (ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit) values(112,'IFIC A/C',3,null,8000);
go
```

I want to sum values from all the children of a specific node. For example, for the top-level `Assets` note I expect:

```
Name       Debit          Credit
Assets    20000          30000
```

For the second-level `Current Asset` node, I expect:

```
Name             Debit         Credit
Current Asset    20000          30000
```

I can't do that with a simple GROUP BY :

```
select 
    Name,
    SUM(Debit),
    SUM(Credit)
FROM tbl_trial_balance
GROUP BY Name
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You have to gives us a bit more info about what you are actually trying to achieve. Could you also please share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question. Use an *appropriate* title, explain what the problem is and what you tried. "I can't get the data" mean anything without the *query* you used. Solving this is impossible if you don't explain what you expected and what you got. `SELECT * FROM tbl_trial_balance` obviously works

Comment: I am creating  Trial Balance

Comment: @AminurRahman that's obvious from the `CREATE TABLE` statement. What is the *problem* ? What have you tried?

Comment: @AminurRahman are you looking for a tutorial on SQL and GROUP BY perhaps? Then SO isn't the proper place to post - it's a Q&A site, not a discussion or tutorial site

Comment: you need to explain how you get the desired output you are showing, for example how are the parent codes relating to the ids and what values do you want to SUM? I can't see how you are getting to those totals from what you have provided. it looks like you want some kind of recursive cte for the parent child totals, but it's not clear.

Comment: @AminurRahman the new title is as bad as the previous one. Explain the **problem**. Are you asking how to group hierarchical data by the top-level categories? You'll find many similar SO answers then. Some use recursive CTEs, some use the `hierarchyid` instead of a self-join

Comment: @AminurRahman I edited the title and question to actually say that you want to sum hierarchical data. The numbers you posted though can't come from *this* data.  `Debit` for `Assets` should be 20K not 7K, `Credit` 30K not 120K. Where did these numbers come from?

Comment: Sorry This is typing mistake .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if the desired output *was* a typo, then you can use this:

```
;with x as (
    select ID,Name,Parent_code,Debit,Credit from tbl_trial_balance where parent_code is null

    union all

    select t.ID, x.name, t.Parent_code, t.Debit, t.Credit from tbl_trial_balance t join x on t.parent_code = x.id
)
select name, sum(credit) credit, sum(debit) debit from x group by name
```